How does the OSPM know if an incoming interrupt is SCI or not?
According to the ACPI spec:

The SCI interrupt is deﬁned to be a shareable interrupt and is connected to an OS visible interrupt that uses a shareable
protocol. The FADT has an entry that indicates what interrupt the SCI interrupt is mapped to.


As I understand, the SCI needs to be claimed by the OSPM (a subsystem in OS for power management and platform configuration).
My question is:
Since SCI is just a normal interrupt, how does OSPM tell if an incoming interrupt is a SCI or not before claiming it?
Below are some quote from this thread:

Once one knows the IRQ number it is easy to get the INT number, the OS generally can easily make a table for that purpose since it is well known (or can be known with the ACPI tables) how the interrupt controllers are connected to the CPUs.

The above SCI_EN field contains the IRQ# for the SCI (according to ACPI spec: Global System Interrupts can be thought of as ACPI Plug and Play IRQ numbers.).
And OS should have a table to map the IRQ# to Interrupt Vector (the INT number in above quote) by collecting the platform's interrupt routing info.
So my guess is, when an interrupt arrives, OS must know its vector number, and OS look up the table for its IRQ#, and check if the IRQ# equals SCI_INT. If it is, OS will know it is a SCI and let the OSPM claim it.
Is this correct?

The OS knowns the interrupt controller mapping, i.e. what IRQ line maps to what interrupt vector. For the 8259 case, the PIC is just programmed to add a fixed base to the serving IRQ. For the IO APIC and the MSI the vector is programmed into the entry (a fixed interrupt it's just a kind of interrupt deliverable by the IO APIC/MSI). If you are asking about how can the OS discern when the SCI is actually a SCI e not a normal interrupt sharing the same IRQ, then the usual techniques apply. Each driver registering an ISR for that interrupt will check the device status register. This is true for...

... any shared interrupt, not just for SCI. A driver can then tell if it's its device that raised an interrupt and act accordingly. In the SCI case, this may be a fallback. I don't remember if there's a global event status register, but it's not strictly necessary.
